# How Can I Prevent AJAX From Destroying My Session?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-4

I'm currently building a web application using CodeIgniter 4. In one of my forms, I need ajax to send a post request and get the data result to modify the form base on item selected on a combo box.
The first requests were always okay, but it won't work for the next one. When I refresh the page, it redirects me to login page, due to my filter. It turns out that the AJAX request either destroy all my sessions, or update it to the new ones.

this is my ajax :

`

```
$('#penilaian_jenis').on('change', function() {
       
        $.ajax({
  OST          type: "P",
            url: '<?= base_url('guru/penilaian/get_nilai') ?>',
            data: {
                'kelas_id': '<?= $kelas->kelas_id ?>',
                'kd_id': '<?= $kd->kd_id ?>',
                'penilaian_jenis': $('#penilaian_jenis').val(),
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(result);
            }
        })
    })
```

`

This is my Controller :
`

```
public function get_nilaii()
    {

        echo json_encode('success');
    }
```

`
This is how I stored my session at the auth controller:

```
 $data = [
                    'user' => $user,
                    'guru' => $model->where('user_id', $user->user_id)->first(),
                    'guru_logged_in' => 1,
                ];
                session()->set($data);
```

My Ajax codes I user are the simplest one. Can Anyone help give me the solutions to this problem, or recommend me another way to do HTML request without losing all my sessions?

Sorry for bad grammar, and thank you in advance

Comment: I dont think the ajax would destroy session. The question is how do you store your session in the first place?

Comment: I edited my post. Please check out the method I used to store my session. @IbrahimHammed

Comment: I guess, maybe your `session` is not actually saving. Try put this: `php_value session.auto_start 1` in your `.htaccess`

Comment: *When I refresh the page, it redirects me to login page, due to my filter*, this could also be the result of not renewing CSRF (server-side) before receiving success of Ajax. Then the next call will fail! This scenario in case you have [Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html?highlight=csrf#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)  enabled

Comment: AND: what CI 4 version are you using?

Comment: I suspect it is a session setting in your Config\App.php or Config\Cookies files - have a look at session refresh times and whether your cookies are accessible to javascript and that might help.